# How to replicate a set of custom fields in a page or custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I need to give to my client an easy way to manage a textual calendar page.

It should consist basically of small elements to insert in the page organized like this:

```
Month name
13/07/2015 - Some text
15/07/2015 - Some other text

Other Month name
13/08/2015 - Some text
15/08/2015 - Some other text
```

And so on.

I'm not sure which way to go to achieve something like this. I thought about:

1) creating a calendar page and manage everything with a predefined set of custom fields, having the possiblity to replicate the same set of fields. But I'm not sure if this is actually possible.

2) creating a custom post type for calendar with a couple of custom fields, so what the client would need to do would be to just create a new post. But still if I want to group event by months I think I would need the possibility to replicate the custom fields in a post.

If it's not clear what I mean by "replicate": let's say that I have a group of two custom fields in a post: one is the date and the other is the text. I want them to automatically appear in the admin panel and the client would just need to press "add" to add another copy of the same fields.

How can I do something like this, possibly without using a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said "possibly without using a plugin", but if you were to use a plugin, take a look at Advanced Custom Fields Pro. It makes adding custom fields to your Wordpress site a breeze.

Using the Repeater field, this can easily be achieved. You can create a set of fields, and then, on the page, you can add as many sets of the fields as you like. You can optionally set a min and max on number of field sets.

I use this plugin extensively on all the sites I dev, so I purchased the Developer license ($100), but the single-site license is only $25. But if you dev multiple WordPress sites, I'd recommend the Dev License.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/

Documentation on the Repeater Field:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

The code is rather simple to display the repeater's content on your page template. For this example, let's say your repeater is named 'my_repeater', and you have 2 text input fields called 'text_1' and 'text_2'.

```
<?php // check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('my_repeater') ):
    echo '<div id="repeaterContainer">';
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('my_repeater') ) : the_row();

            // display a sub field value
            echo '<h2>'.get_sub_field('text_1').'</h2>';
            echo '<p>'.get_sub_field('text_2').'</p>';
            echo '<hr />';

        endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
else :

// no rows found

endif; ?>
```

This would output the following html:

```
<div id="repeaterContainer">
    <h2>My Text</h2>
    <p>Second Field Text</p>
    <hr />
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>More Text Here</p>
    <hr />
    <h2>More Text</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <hr />
    <h2>My Extra Text</h2>
    <p>Here is some more text for a custom field.</p>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this has actually been useful. Not sure if I'm going to use that plugin, but looking at other similar ones I've found this one: http://customfieldsuite.com/. It seems to be enough for my needs